# What does Invariants in Classes means in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, class, invariants

I came across the word **invariants**.

From the statement: Don't break superclass invariants.

(This is based from WWDC15 Video - Protocol-Oriented Programming. It's a discussion about Class inheritance being intrusive and if it contains stored properties, you don't want to break superclass invariants.)

You can watch it at https://youtu.be/g2LwFZatfTI?t=9m10s

The video will start to the point related to it.)

But I don't really know what invariant means?

I tried to search the web and there is no clear definition about it is?

How does it relate to inheritance of classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more context. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: Where did you come across the statement?

Comment: Hi @JoshCaswell and uchuuugaka, I have updated my question. Thanks for pointing this out.